# How can a function with asymptotes be defined as a mapping?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

A mapping takes each element of a set S and associates it with an element t in some other set T. I believe functions to be mappings. Yet we happily call such as $\frac {x^2}{x+1}$ a function, even though for the value x = -1 there is no mapping from x to f(x) and hence there is not an association between each element of our set S to some other set. 
Where am I going wrong?
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The domain of function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is the set $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ (not $\mathbb R$). For each element of this domain there is - what you call - a mapping.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R - \{-1\}$? If so, then that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\mathbb R-\{-1\}$. Sorry for my mistake.